# Base three numbers and expanded form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I need help understanding this. Write each of the following base three numerals in expanded notation.

1. $22_3$
2. $212_3$
3. $12110_3$

Comment: What is expanded notation?  My guess is something like $123_{10}=1\cdot 10^2+2\cdot 10^1 +3\cdot 10^0$.  If so, what is your problem?

Comment: I don't understand what the base three means and expanded notation.

Comment: We don't have a single symbol for every number, so we repeat symbols and use the location of the digit to give us more information.  Where in decimal (our usual base 10), the number $234 = 200+30+4=2\cdot 10^2 + 3\cdot 10^1 + 4\cdot 10^0$, the location tells us "how much that digit is worth (in terms of powers of ten)".  In a different base, say base $b$, you have $112_b=1\cdot b^2 + 1\cdot b^1 + 2\cdot b^0$ and the location of the digit tells us "how much that digit is worth (in terms of powers of b).  So, for base 3, $22_3 = ...$ and $212_3=...$

Comment: "Expanded notation" is not a term I recognize, so maybe it is defined in your text (if you have one).  I took a guess, which I thought was a reasonable one.  What do you know about base 3?  You should be able to make an analogy from my base 10 answer to base 3(Hint:  replace 10s by 3s, but that won't show you understand what base 3 means)

Answer (score 1):

Surely this means to expand them into base ten ...

So 22 in base three is actually 8 in base ten (this is 2 + (2*3)).
212 in base three is actually 14 in base ten (this is 2 + 1*3 + 2*9).
12110 in base three is actually 147 in base ten.

Answer (score -2):

If you are being asked to write numbers in the expanded notation for Base $3$ such as $112201_3$ (just a random number I made up) then you would need to write it like so (starting from the $3^5$th place, the 5th place of the digit)

$$112201_3 = 1.3^5 + 1.3^4 + 2.3^3 + 2.3^2+ 0.3^1 + 1.3^0$$

Use this video to help yourself understand 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOyiHMa-mtQ